# function interpretar_data($data)

Tags: php

Como filtrar boletos por Data? O meu esta aleatório. Podem ajudar?

```
      function interpretar_cobranca($cobranca)
  {
$status = "pago";
$valorpago = $cobranca->valorpago;
$datavencimento = $cobranca->datavencimento;

if ($valorpago == 0) {
    if ($cobranca->dias_vencidos > 0)
        $status = "vencido";
    else
        $status = "aberto";
}

return $status;
 }

   function interpretar_extra($cobranca)
  {
$extra = '-';

$valorpago = $cobranca->valorpago;
$mora = $cobranca->dias_vencidos * $cobranca->mora;

      if ($valorpago == 0 && $cobranca->dias_vencidos > 1)
    $extra = "Venceu h&aacute; " . $cobranca->dias_vencidos . "       dias<br><b>Mora: " . 
        money_format("%.2n", $mora) . " Multa: " . 
        money_format("%.2n", $cobranca->multa) .       "</b><br>                                                                                  <b>Valor    total: " . 
        money_format("%.2n", $cobranca->valor + $mora +                     $cobranca->multa) . "</b>";

return $extra;
 }

    function interpretar_data($data)
 { 
if (empty($data))
    return '-';

       return gmdate('d/m/Y', $data);
```

Comment: Poderia dar mais detalhes?

Comment: Os boletos apareçem , mas nao em ordem !!!

Comment: O seu código não tem nenhum `for`. Pode postar a parte que *lista* os boletos que você quer que apareçam em ordem?

Comment: pronto !! editei

Comment: `$cliente->cobrancas` é populado por uma consulta ao banco de dados, imagino? Pode postar a consulta que popula esse campo?

Comment: Coloque o código que obtém as cobranças para obter respostas mais aprofundadas, mas caso esteja obtendo através de um banco SQL adicione um `ORDER BY` na consulta.

Comment: eu nao tenho acesso ao banco ainda,  estou fazendo a consulta atraves um web service em SOAP  ,,  a linha das datas esta assim !

Comment: <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="id"                            type="xs:integer"/><xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="nossonumero" type="xs:string"/><xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="dataemissao" type="xs:integer"/><xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="datavencimento" type="xs:integer"/><xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="datapagamento" type="xs:integer"/><xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="dias_vencidos" type="xs:integer"/>

Comment: Votei para fechar como "Não é claro o que você está perguntando" porque realmente eu não consegui entender direito a sua pergunta. Seria legal você tentar explicar melhor o que você quer, além de tentar organizar melhor o código.

Comment: entao,, desculpe é que to meio afobado !!!   Faço a consulta simples atraves de um web service no meu php ,,,,  porem ao listar os boletos as datas aparecem fora de ordem !!! eu queria organizar as datas....mas nao consigo de jeito nenhum  ,,,o que precisam de fato ???

Comment: Fora da ordem seria por exemplo os primeiros seriam todos os dias 31, depois os 30, 29 etc?